# Vertical menu using Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap plugin for vertical menu,my requirement is when i reduce my window size to mobile size or open this in mobile i need to display only the images which i used in vertical menu "li" tag and the text should not be displayed and the menu size is reduced.Can you help me with this The code i have written is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<section id="page">
    <!-- SIDEBAR -->

    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">

    <div class="sidebar-menu nav-collapse" >
    <div class="divide-20"></div>
    <!-- SIDEBAR COLLAPSE -->
    <div id="sidebar-collapse" class="sidebar-collapse">
            <i class="fa fa-bars" 
    data-icon1="fa fa-bars" 
    data-icon2="fa fa-bars" ></i>
    </div>

    <!-- /SIDEBAR COLLAPSE -->

    <!-- SIDEBAR MENU -->
        <ul>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span class="menu-text">Section1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i> <span class="menu-text">Section2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> <span class="menu-text">Section3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i><span class="menu-text">Section4</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> <span class="menu-text">Section5</span></a></li>




    </ul>
<!-- /SIDEBAR MENU -->
</div>
    </div>
<!-- /SIDEBAR -->
```

Answer (score 1):

*If you don't want some part to don't appear in XS view , just add `hidden-xs` class on it :*

**Exemple** : `<span class="menu-text hidden-xs">Section2</span>`

**HTML** :

```
  <!-- SIDEBAR MENU -->
        <ul>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span class="menu-text hidden-xs">Section1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i> <span class="menu-text hidden-xs">Section2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> <span class="menu-text hidden-xs">Section3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i><span class="menu-text hidden-xs">Section4</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> <span class="menu-text">Section5</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

**Here is a minimal bootply :** http://www.bootply.com/cxeL7BWMlB

**You can find the official doc here :** http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Thank u.For the help,but when i attach this hidden-xs  class its showing the text in one line and image in other line and also the menu width is not reducing.The output required is the same when we click on "#sidebar-collapse" its showing the output i need the same when window size is reduced

Comment: Thanks for the help.I've got the output the side menu is being collapsed to side with width:50px; it's showing default message "hide" but i need the icons in that place can you help with this?